# Mathjax not rendering properly on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, latex, mathjax

I have a wordpress.org blog, and I use Mathjax for my latex code. One of my equations isn't rendering properly on my [latest post](https://recreational-engineer.com/how-intense-is-sunlight-at-different-latitudes/).

Here's the code I'm using:

[k^{\sec x}\cdot \frac{\cos x}{k}]

[(how it renders for me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loulX.png)

The x in sec x is slightly lower than it should be, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried it on Safari on two different macs and my iPhone, and I keep getting the same probelm.

(I've already tested the code on the live demo on the Mathjax website, and it renders fine there.)

Answer (score 1):

This turns out to be a bug specific to MathJax's CommonHTML output on Safari.

See https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1710 for more information.